# Webscraping: Issues with using findAll in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to grab all the languages from this website https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/ali-shahrestani-esq-198352.

The line of code I have only gives me part of what I want.

```
soup.findAll("div",{"class":"block-wrapper block"})
```

Output: '[English: Spoken, Written]'

Based on the tags, I have also tried

```
soup.findAll("ul",{"class":"has-no-list-styles"})
```

Output: 'Personal InjuryProducts LiabilityElder LawConsumer LawDUI & DWIEmployment Law'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, I think:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/ali-shahrestani-esq-198352'
data = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(data.text,'lxml')
target = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"heading-3 block-title iconed-heading font-w-bold"})
for t in target:
    if t.find('span', class_="jicon -large jicon-languages"):
        langs = t.find_next_sibling()
        for lang in langs.find_all('li'):
            print(lang.text)
```

Output:

```
English: Spoken, Written
French: Spoken, Written
Italian: Spoken, Written
Persian: Spoken
Spanish: Spoken, Written
```